# Two separate Log4j log files possible?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I run two web services on the same machine.

Is it possible to have 2 separate Log4j log files, one for each web service?

Comment: What is the underlying problem you need to solve?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'd like to have two logs, so I can debug easier. Currently both services write to same log file and that's confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some code samples that solve this problem:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

<appender name="fileAppender1" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
   <param name="file" value="webservice1.log"/>
</appender>

<appender name="fileAppender2" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
   <param name="file" value="webservice2.log"/>
</appender>

<logger name="org.x.logger1">
   <appender ref="fileAppender1"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.x.logger2">
   <appender ref="fileAppender2"/>
</logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Read also this posts:

[Apache Log4j - Logging Separation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/logsep.html)

and [SO - How to create different log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630522/how-to-create-different-log-files-for-different-packages-using-same-log4j-logger)

Answer (score 0):

If your two services are in separated web application, you can simply include log4j in each webapp and include a log4j.properties that logs in a dedicated file.