# how to use different log files for class or package using Java Utility Logging?

Tags: java

I am using Java Utility Logging with java application project for exception handling.
how to use different  log files for class or package using Java Utility Logging?
if it is possible with JUL then what kind of change are required in property file?
Is there any other way to use this feature using JUL?

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for with `Log4j`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652032/how-can-i-create-2-separate-log-files-with-one-log4j-config-file

Comment: i agree...but that means JUL doesn't contain this feature or using some other way it is possible in JUL.

Comment: I have seen code of log4j  for  using different log file from link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630522/how-to-create-different-log-files-for-different-packages-using-same-log4j-logger.


i think using this logic...we can also create different log files for different log file.

suggest me if i am wrong.