# How to create multiple log files using log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to create separate log file 
one for info another for debug,
I am using below log4j.property file,
Please suggest how to modify for two level logging in different file,

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=info, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=infoLog.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n


log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, console     
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
```

I would like to request Please send me updated property file rather than giving pointer for search or explore, because I have already spent 3-4 Hours on searching this solution in Google and StackOverflow,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have already seen [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728295/creating-multiple-log-files-of-different-content-with-log4j) ? If No, then take a look

Comment: You can check here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630522/how-to-create-different-log-files-for-different-packages-using-same-log4j-logger


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652032/how-can-i-create-2-separate-log-files-with-one-log4j-config-file

Comment: @Sharp edge- I have already checked and modified as per our need its giving error as- log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.LoudAppender.layout
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.TRACE
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "TRACE".
log4j:ERROR No layout set for the appender named [LoudAppender].

Comment: @AmareshPattanayak- its logging only one file package2 and only info, I want both info and debug both -your suggested property file updated as-#log4j.rootLogger=package1,package2

log4j.appender.package1=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender 
log4j.appender.package1.File=package1.log
log4j.appender.package1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.package2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.package2.File=package2.log
log4j.appender.package2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.logger.mypack.test.testing=DEBUG,package1
log4j.logger.mypack.test.testing=info,package2

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,Appender2

log4j.logger.infoMessagesLogger=INFO, infoMessagesAppender
log4j.additivity.infoMessagesLogger=false

log4j.logger.debugMessagesAppender=DEBUG, debugAppenderAll
log4j.additivity.debugMessagesAppender=false

log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=generic.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.Appender2.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss } %-5p %c %x -%m%n


log4j.appender.infoMessagesAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.infoMessagesAppender.File=info.log
log4j.appender.infoMessagesAppender.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.infoMessagesAppender.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.infoMessagesAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.infoMessagesAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss } %-5p %c %x -%m%n

log4j.appender.debugAppenderAll=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.debugAppenderAll.File=debug.log
log4j.appender.debugAppenderAll.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.debugAppenderAll.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.debugAppenderAll.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.debugAppenderAll.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss } %-5p %c %x -%m%n
```

Comment: @Rahul-Thanks its working but not logging debug messages,only info messages its logging,I have both message in my program both has to be looged

Comment: @Rahul-also tell me why you used Appender2 and infoMessagesAppender both are same I guess.

Comment: are you using Logger.getLogger("debugMessagesAppender") to log debug messages ?