# DailyRollingFileAppender not creating daily log file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, logging, log4j, rollingfileappender

DailyRollingFileAppender is not creating daily backup log file.

I am using the below config, which works on my local machine but it not working on the machine where my project has been deployed.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, Appender2

log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=C:/Logs/AppLog.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.DatePattern='.'dd-MM-yyyy
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.Appender2.rootLogger = DEBUG
```

Framework - Spring MVC

I am not able to understand which part of the config is bloking DailyRollingFileAppender  to create date wise log on my server machine.

**Edit-**

I updated my file as per the suggestion and it is not creating a new backup file at 12 am next day. means it updated AppLog.l‌​og till 12 then there was no backup file and all the previous day logs are gone and it starts writing from the beginning.

This is log4j properties now-

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, Appender2
log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=${catalina.home}/Logs/AppLog.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.Append=false
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
```

Comment: There are no different properties. I am using the same code on both the machines.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the file path here:

```
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=C:/Logs/AppLog.log
```

Please make sure that this path exists on the server where you have deployed your project.

Comment: The path exists. Code is generating a log file. Its not generating daily date wise log.

Comment: Which log4j version are you using?

Comment: 1.2.17

<dependency>
 <groupId>log4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Try changing the date pattern to `'.'yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: Tried this too, didn't work.I am using Spring MVC framework. Is there some special settings for that?

Comment: Try removing this line `log4j.appender.Appender2.rootLogger`

Answer (score 0):

I faced with this problem before, the cause turned to be I used wrong `log4j` dependency in `pom.xml`. The previous dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

I use spring boot in my project, so I changed it to the following, it worked.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am using the same setting as you were using previously. Do you know the dependency in pom.xml for Spring-MVC?

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-web` if you use spring boot, otherwise declare `spring-webmvc` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

your DatePattern should be '.'yyyy-MM-dd

refer to  https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html

Comment: I tried your method, still no luck. I am using Spring MVC as my framework.

Answer (score -1):

u can use this for get the daily rolling log file,

```
########## Appender Daily Rolling
log4j.logger.appender=Daily
log4j.appender.Daily=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Daily.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.Daily.File=D:/backup/RFLI1010.log
log4j.appender.Daily.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
# Append to the end of the file or overwrites the file at start.
log4j.appender.Daily.Append=true
log4j.appender.Daily.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.Daily.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Daily.layout.ConversionPattern=  [%5p] %d %r %t (%F:%M:%L)%m%n%n
```

Comment: Tried your way but it did not make any changes. Also shouldn't log4j.appender.Daily.Append be false? if I write true then it will append to same file, right?

Comment: yes. if true means it will append same file. also share ur log4j.property ?

Comment: I have done some changes in the file- 
llog4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, Appender2
 
log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=${catalina.home}/Logs/AppLog.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.Append=false
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n

Comment: Now it is creating a new file at 12 AM, but no backup file. means it starts writing in the same file from the beginning.

Comment: log4j.appender.Appender2.Append=true.did u checked like this?

Comment: I tried, not on 12 am next day its not creating a new log file and not even writing in old one. means it updated AppLog.l‌​og till 12 then there was no backup file and code is not updating AppLog.l‌​og either.

Comment: see this link, it might be help,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941144/how-to-create-multiple-log-files-using-log4j

Comment: sry. it is updating the log file. It appending the log file with next day logs also. Still no backup file.